# How to include SHA and timestamp of original commits in the commit message of a squashed commit?

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase, squash, git-squash

I understand that changing anything in a commit is going to change its SHA. This question is NOT about preserving the SHA of a commit.

When I do a `git rebase -i <commit-sha>` and squash a bunch of commits using `pick` and `squash`, the resultant commit message is something like the following:

```
# This is a combination of 8 commits.
# This is the 1st commit message:

blah blah

# This is the commit message #1:

more blah...

# This is the commit message #2:

even more blah...

# This is the commit message #3:

and so on...
```

Is there any way to get the following:

```
# This is a combination of 8 commits.
# This is the 1st commit message:

Original Author: __________
Original SHA: ___________
Original Date: __________

blah blah

# This is the commit message #2:

Original Author: __________
Original SHA: ___________
Original Date: __________

more blah...

(and so on)
```